# How long do word vectors typically need to be?

Tags: word2vec, word-embeddings

I was wondering how long word vectors typically are.  I was working on an RNN language translator and I was using word vectors of size 128 to model english and german words.  I seemed to get good results after a day of training.  Do you think I need to use shorter or longer vectors?  I did a google search and I can not find any rule of thumb for vector length.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the dataset, and ANN architecture.  Machine translation systems tend to use high dimensions, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3215.pdf use 1000 dimensional word embeddings.